# SQLite db create error in real iOS device

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm trying to learning swiftUi and I've included SQLIte in my project. I've successfully created db, tables and func to read and insert records and I tested it in Xcode emulator and all works fine. I'm using Xcode 12.1. When I try to launch my app to real device (iphone 11, software version 13.5.1), the db isn't create and I get this error:

> 2021-04-14 18:00:59.296690+0200 playToys[285:7409] [logging-persist]
> cannot open file at line 43353 of [378230ae7f] 2021-04-14
> 18:00:59.296742+0200 playToys[285:7409] [logging-persist]
> os_unix.c:43353: (0)
> open(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3D858B04-DA3A-488E-804A-DFD13DD882E3/Documents.playToysDb.sqlite)
>
> - Undefined error: 0 There is error in creating DB puntamento creazionefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3D858B04-DA3A-488E-804A-DFD13DD882E3/Documents.playToysDb.sqlite/
>   2021-04-14 18:00:59.298066+0200 playToys[285:7409] [logging] API call
>   with NULL database connection pointer 2021-04-14 18:00:59.298104+0200
>   playToys[285:7409] [logging] misuse at line 131400 of [378230ae7f]
>   Prepration table cliente fail 2021-04-14 18:00:59.298127+0200
>   playToys[285:7409] [logging] API call with NULL database connection
>   pointer 2021-04-14 18:00:59.298142+0200 playToys[285:7409] [logging]
>   misuse at line 131400 of [378230ae7f] Prepration createing Currencies
>   table fail 2021-04-14 18:00:59.298161+0200 playToys[285:7409]
>   [logging] API call with NULL database connection pointer 2021-04-14
>   18:00:59.298174+0200 playToys[285:7409] [logging] misuse at line
>   131400 of [378230ae7f] Prepration createing Categorie table fail

This is a part of code to create and open db:

```
class  DBHelper {
    static let dbHelperInstance = DBHelper()
    var db : OpaquePointer?
    var path : String = "playToysDb.sqlite"
    private init() {}
    
    
    func initDatabase(){
        self.db = createDB()
        self.createTableCurrency()
        self.initDefaultItems()
    }
  func createDB() -> OpaquePointer? {
          let filePath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathExtension(path)

          
          var dbPointer : OpaquePointer? = nil
          
          if sqlite3_open(filePath.path, &dbPointer) != SQLITE_OK {
              print("There is error in creating DB")
          
              return nil
          }else {
              print("Database has been created with path \(path)")
              return dbPointer
          }
        
        
      }
    
    
    func openDatabase()
    {

        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathExtension(path)

        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
            print("Database Created !!")
        }

    }

}
```

Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `appendingPathExtension`. That is for adding an extension to a filename. You meant [`appendingPathComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780239-appendingpathcomponent), which is for adding an entire filename (or other path component) to a URL.

That is why you are seeing a `.` between `Documents` and your filename, rather than a `/`, in the path shown in your error message. The simulator will blithely create a file called `Documents.playToysDb.sqlite` in your app’s root directory, but a device cannot. It expects it to be within the `Documents` directory, resulting in the failure when trying to create that file.

---

You asked about the correct way to get the database URL. A few observations:

1. You asked about `urls(for:in:)[0]` vs `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`. I would use the latter.
2. I would advise using `.applicationSupportDirectory` rather than `.documentDirectory`. The former is for the app’s support files. The latter is intended for user-facing files, which is not appropriate here. You can use `.documentDirectory`, but I would not advise it.
3. I would also avoid repeating this open in `createDB` and `openDatabase`. In fact, I would have a single method that would try to open the existing database, and if it fails, only then create the database and create/populate the tables.
4. Implicit in the above point, I would advise `sqlite3_open_v2`, in which you can chose to create a blank database or not. So I call it first without `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` (which, if successful, I know the database has already been created). Only if that fails do I try it again with that option (and then proceed to create the necessary tables).

Thus:

```swift
class DBHelper {
    static let shared = DBHelper()

    private var db: OpaquePointer?
    private let filename = "playToysDb.sqlite"

    private init() {
        openDatabase()
    }
}

private extension DBHelper {
    var errorMessage: String {
        sqlite3_errmsg(db).flatMap { String(cString: $0) } ?? "Unknown Error"
    }

    func openDatabase() {
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent(filename)

        // try to open existing database (but don't create); if successful, return immediately

        if sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            print("Database has been opened with path \(fileURL.path)")
            return
        }

        // if you got here, clean up and then try creating database

        sqlite3_close(db) // clean up after the above `sqlite3_open` call

        guard sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
            print("There is error in creating DB: ", errorMessage)
            sqlite3_close(db) // if creation failed, make sure to again clean up
            db = nil
            return
        }

        // if you got here, we created blank database, so populate however you want

        createTableCurrency()
        populateDefaultItems()

        print("Database has been created with path \(fileURL.path)")
    }

    func createTableCurrency() { ... }

    func populateDefaultItems() { ... }
}
```

Note, in addition to the above, I have tackled a few unrelated observations:

- As a matter of convention, I used `shared` for the name of the shared instance.
- I would mark the private properties and methods as such, to avoid external manipulation of them.
- If a query ever fails, I would call `sqlite3_errmsg` to get the error reported by SQLite.
- If open fails, always call `sqlite3_close`. As the [docs say](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html):

  > Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle should be released by passing it to [`sqlite3_close()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) when it is no longer required.

Comment: Thanks you Rob for your explanation and your patience. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for reply. I solved my issue using appendingPathComponent and using the first directory available for the user. Is that a correct way?

```
class  DBHelper {
    static let dbHelperInstance = DBHelper()
    var db : OpaquePointer?
    var path : String = "playToysDb.sqlite"
    private init() {}
    
    
    func initDatabase(){
        self.db = createDB()
        self.createTableCurrency()
        self.initDefaultItems()
    }
  func createDB() -> OpaquePointer? {
 let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(path);

          
          var dbPointer : OpaquePointer? = nil
          
          if sqlite3_open(filePath.path, &dbPointer) != SQLITE_OK {
              print("There is error in creating DB")
          
              return nil
          }else {
              print("Database has been created with path \(path)")
              return dbPointer
          }
        
        
      }
    
    
    func openDatabase()
    {

       let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(path);

        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
            print("Database Created !!")
        }

    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        // find all possible documents directories for this user
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

        // just send back the first one, which ought to be the only one
        return paths[0]
    }

}
```

This approach works too, which is the differences?

```
class  DBHelper {
        static let dbHelperInstance = DBHelper()
        var db : OpaquePointer?
        var path : String = "playToysDb.sqlite"
        private init() {}
        func initDatabase(){
            self.db = createDB()
            self.createTableCurrency()
            self.initDefaultItems()
        }
      func createDB() -> OpaquePointer? {
      let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent(path)
    
              
              var dbPointer : OpaquePointer? = nil
              
              if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &dbPointer) != SQLITE_OK {
                  print("There is error in creating DB")
              
                  return nil
              }else {
                  print("Database has been created with path \(path)")
                  return dbPointer
              }
            
            
          }
        
        
        func openDatabase()
        {
    
              let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent(path)

    
            if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
                print("Database Created !!")
            }
    
        }
    
     
    
    }
```

Comment: Regarding grabbing the first URL from `urls(for:in:)` vs just calling `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`, I would always advise the latter.